# d3 get pixel coordinates of center of circle svg element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get the center of a circle in a callback:

```
var el = d3.select(this);
console.log(el.toString());
  // [object SVGCircleElement]

var cx = el.attr('cx');
console.log('cx: ' + cx);
  // cx: [object SVGCircleElement]

cx = el.style('cx');
console.log('cx: ' + cx);
  // cx: [object SVGCircleElement]

var x = el.attr('x');
console.log('x: ' + x);
  // x: [object SVGCircleElement]

x = el.style('x');
console.log('x: ' + x);
  // x: [object SVGCircleElement]
```

I was expecting one of those 4 to give me a value like `"10px"`. How would I find out some coordinates relating to where the circle is?

Comment: At least `cx` should give you something. Can you post the complete code please?

Comment: Was in the callback for https://github.com/aj0strow/mcgill-steam/blob/master/public/js/graph.js#L23 but I took it out for the time being

Comment: Do you have a minimal example?

Comment: considering 'cx' should work, i'll thoroughly debug monday or tuesday, so I'll post again then if I can't figure it out :)